# How do I pull info from my outputs into a MessageBox

Tags: c#

I figured out my percent, calculation stuff.  Now I need to display a message after calculation that indicates the type of car rented, the number of days and the rental total.

//These are my radio buttons

```
private void rdoVehicle_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   string rdoName = ((RadioButton)sender).Name;   //name of selected radio button
   switch (rdoName) 
   {
       case "rdoEconomy": vehicleCost = ECONOMY; break;
       case "rdoLuxury": vehicleCost = LUXURY; break;
       case "rdoVan" : vehicleCost = VAN; break;
       case "rdoTruck": vehicleCost = TRUCK; break;
       case "rdoSuv": vehicleCost = SUV; break;
   }//end switch
}
```

txtDays, is my txt property for number of days being rented
and lblRentalTotal is my output label for the rental total.

MessageBox.Show(?????????????????)

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line of your code, hit F5 and step through your code in the debugger.  you can inspect the values at each line - this should quickly tell you why your if statements are "basically ignored".

Comment: Check `PROMODAYS`, this might be some constant field and that condition might be true always + some radio is checked, you need to debug and check - this is what my suggestion after looking add code.

Comment: My PROMODAYS is assigned 4.  I am suppose to calculate if they rent a luxury car for more than 3 days, you receive a 15% discount and PROMODISCOUNT is set at 0.15

Comment: My discount is coming back as the same amount as the rentalTotal

Answer (score 0):

There will be 2 events firing if all radio buttons are wired to the same event:

1. One fires when one radio button is unchecked.
2. The other fires when the new radio button is checked.

Check which radio button was checked in the event handler:

```
private void rdoVehicle_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    var rad = ((RadioButton)sender);
    if(!rad.Checked)
        return; 

    switch (rad.Name) 
    {
        case "rdoEconomy": vehicleCost = ECONOMY; break;
        case "rdoLuxury": vehicleCost = LUXURY; break;
        case "rdoVan" : vehicleCost = VAN; break;
        case "rdoTruck": vehicleCost = TRUCK; break;
        case "rdoSuv": vehicleCost = SUV; break;
    }
}
```

Comment: all rdo buttons are wired to btnCalculate_click

Comment: would that go after my initial switch statement.  I'm in programming beginning if you could not tell

Comment: The example code you posted used `rdoVehicle_CheckedChanged` without any mention of a `btnCalculate_click` event handler. The answer I provided uses the exact code you posted w/ the addition of only evaluating the `switch` when the radio button is in the checked state. Any additional work that needs to be done, such as adding text to a label, should be added after the switch statement.

Comment: The checkChanged event is used to determine the value to be used in the calculation once all the user decisions have been made and they then calculate.  Its at that point our instructor wants us to display a message that indicates the type of car rented, the number of days its being rented for and what the rental total is

Comment: Would it help if I posted everything but btnCalculate down to the bottom?

Comment: There is some missing information from the question, such as what is the actual problem you're encountering, re: the question is a bit confusing since there are references to things extraneous to the actual issue. As this is your first question on S.O., you should read the ["How do I ask a good question"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And welcome to S.O.!

Comment: Sorry if I did things wrong or upset anyone.  I won't ask anymore questions.  My apologies.

Comment: @AlanLeonhardt - you didn't do anything wrong or upset anyone. The question is just hard to understand. I posted the link on how to ask a good question to help you in re-writing your question.